# Eclipse wrongly formats a Spring p-namespace bean

Tags: eclipse, spring, code-formatting, spring-2.5

I am using spring-2.5 (cannot upgrade, product dependency) and I notice a strange behaviour of the Eclipse formatter when I am using the p-namespace notation and some value expression:

If I use the standard way (without p-namespace) like this:

```
<bean id="ldapConfig" class="org.mycompany.project.config.LDAPConfig">
<property name="ldapServer" value="${ldap.server}" />
<property name="ldapPort" value="${ldap.port}" />
<property name="ldapBindDn" value="${ldap.bindDn}" />
<property name="ldapPass" value="${ldap.password}" />
</bean>
```

and press the key combination: `Ctrl-Shift-F` the formatting (e.g indentation) works very well.

Now if I use the `p-namespace` notation like this:

```
<bean id="ldapConfig" class="org.mycompany.project.config.LDAPConfig">
<p:ldapServer="${ldap.server}" />
<p:ldapPort="${ldap.port}" />
<p:ldapBindDn="${ldap.bindDn}" />
<p:ldapPass="${ldap.password}"/>
</bean>
```

When I press the key combination: `Ctrl-Shift-F` the formatting (e.g indentation) 
removed some part of the code

```
<bean id="ldapConfig" class="org.mycompany.project.config.LDAPConfig">
    <p:ldapServer = ldap.server } />
    <p:ldapPort = ldap.port } />
    <p:ldapBindDn = ldap.bindDn } />
    <p:ldapPass = ldap.password } />
</bean>
```

Is there any incompatibility between the value expressions ( `${variable}` ) and the p-namespace, or it is just an Eclipse bug on the XML formatting part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bean definition of ldapConfig when using p-namespace is not correct. By using the p-namespace you can use attributes as part of the bean element that describe your property values, instead of using nested  elements. More details can be found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-p-namespace).

Assuming you have declared namespace as xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"

The correct way to use it is:

```
    <bean id="ldapConfig" class="org.mycompany.project.config.LDAPConfig" 
        p:ldapServer="${ldap.server}" 
        p:ldapPort="${ldap.port}" 
        p:ldapBindDn="${ldap.bindDn}" 
        p:ldapPass="${ldap.password}">
    </bean>
```

Now try CTRL-SHIFT-F

Comment: Thanks, so long I didn't use the xml config... I totally forgot the p-namespace are attributes not elements.